# como usar exatamente o sleep e wakeup no python3?(multithread)

Tags: python, multithreading

Olá estou tentando fazer em python3 o famoso problema do produtor/consumidor, transcrevendo do meu livro de S.O. ,porem venho enfrentando um problema , aparentemente o **wait()** so  bota pra dormir uma vez no loop ou algo do tipo, pois simplesmente depois da primeira vez os thread correm soltos.
código:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import threading
acordar_dormir_produtor = threading.Event()
acordar_dormir_consumidor = threading.Event()
bufer = 0
bufer_max = 10


def consumidor():
    global acordar_dormir_produtor
    global acordar_dormir_consumidor
    global bufer
    global bufer_max
    while True:
        if bufer == 0:
            print ("consumidor dormindo")
            acordar_dormir_consumidor.wait()
            print ("consumidor acordou")
        bufer = bufer - 1
        if bufer == (bufer_max - 1):
            print ("distracando produtor")
            acordar_dormir_produtor.set()
            acordar_dormir_produtor.clear()
        print ("consumidor",bufer)


def produtor():
    global acordar_dormir_produtor
    global acordar_dormir_consumidor
    global bufer
    global bufer_max
    while True:
        if bufer == bufer_max:
            print ("produtor dormindo")
            acordar_dormir_produtor.wait()
            print ("produtor acordou")
        bufer = bufer + 1
        if bufer == 1:
            print ("distracando consumidor")
            acordar_dormir_consumidor.set()
            acordar_dormir_produtor.clear()
        print ("produtor ",bufer)
print (bufer)
b = threading.Thread(target=produtor)
a = threading.Thread(target=consumidor)
a.start()
b.start()
#while True:
   # time.sleep(3)
   # print (bufer)
```

como fazer isso? tem outro objeto  já que o **Event** não funciona?
tentei o conditions sem sucesso(na verdade nem chegou a executar)

Answer (score 1):

Usar uma  Queue como o drgarcia sugere é uma solução de mais alto nível para um problema real.

A sua situação no entanto é didática - e isso aqui é o que eu acho que está dando errado:  você chama o `set` e o `clear`  do `Event` em seguida um do outro. A implementação do threading do Python não é algo que usa assinatura de eventos - antes é feita por polling - ou seja, de vez em quando a execução vai passar para a thread que está esperando em um `event.wait` e ver se o seu estado mudou - mas essa verificação não é desencadeada automaticamente pela chamada ao `Event.set` - então vocẽ teria que dar muita (mas muita mesmo)  sorte para a thread ser chamada exatamente entre a sua chaamda  a `set` e a chamada ao `clear` em seguida.

Para o que você fez funcionar, ponha a chamada ao `clear` imediatamente *antes*  da chamada ao `wait` na thread que vai fazer o wait (e não na thread que vai mandar o  `set`):

```
...
def consumidor():
   ...
   acordar_dormir_consumidor.clear()      
   acordar_dormir_consumidor.wait()

...
def produtor():
    ...
    acordar_dormir_consumidor.set()
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a classe `Thread` e a classe `Queue` (que é thread-safe).
Para dormir você pode usar o `time.sleep`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from threading import Thread
import time
import random
from queue import Queue


queue = Queue(10)


class ProducerThread(Thread):
    def run(self):
        nums = range(5)
        global queue
        while True:
            num = random.choice(nums)
            queue.put(num)
            print("Produced", num)
            time.sleep(random.random())


class ConsumerThread(Thread):
    def run(self):
        global queue
        while True:
            num = queue.get()
            queue.task_done()
            print("Consumed", num)
            time.sleep(random.random())


ProducerThread().start()
ConsumerThread().start()
```

O `Producer` alimenta o buffer no método `Queue.put()` enquanto que o `Consumer` lê o buffer através do método `Queue.get()` (e sinalize que a leitura do buffer foi com sucesso através do método `Queue.task_done()`). Após cada um fazer sua tarefa, passa a "dormir" por um tempo randômico.

O método `Queue.get()` espera por um valor na fila, então independente de quem começar a trabalhar primeiro, o consumidor só vai dar sequência quando tiver algo na fila para ser consumidor.

Caso o exemplo necessite ser mais didático, você pode usar a classe `threading.Condition`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from threading import Thread, Condition
import time
import random


queue = []
MAX_NUM = 10
condition = Condition()


class ProducerThread(Thread):
    def run(self):
        nums = range(5)
        global queue
        while True:
            condition.acquire()
            if len(queue) == MAX_NUM:
                print("Queue full, producer is waiting")
                condition.wait()
                print("Space in queue, Consumer notified the producer")
            num = random.choice(nums)
            queue.append(num)
            print("Produced", num)
            condition.notify()
            condition.release()
            time.sleep(random.random())


class ConsumerThread(Thread):
    def run(self):
        global queue
        while True:
            condition.acquire()
            if not queue:
                print("Nothing in queue, consumer is waiting")
                condition.wait()
                print("Producer added something to queue and notified the consumer")
            num = queue.pop(0)
            print("Consumed", num)
            condition.notify()
            condition.release()
            time.sleep(random.random())


ProducerThread().start()
ConsumerThread().start()
```

Com o `condition` você pode fazer o "lock" para controlar quando consumidor e o produtor devem esperar e quando devem trabalhar.

Sendo objetivo na resposta da sua pergunta, o `condition.wait()` faz a thread dormir aguardando o `condition.notify()` que funciona como o "wakeup".

Referência: http://agiliq.com/blog/2013/10/producer-consumer-problem-in-python/